# Extends from Robot handle awtexception

Tags: java, oop, exception, extend, awtrobot

Very simple question: I have a class which extends from java Robot class, however I have an error in my IDE (netbeans), that I haven't handled the AWTException for the my class. how can I fix this?

My class is like this:

```
public class KeyBoard extends Robot{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructors of the class `java.awt.Robot` throw an `AWTException` that requires mandatory handling. So, to solve the problem, declare the constructor of your class to throw an `AWTException`.

```
public class KeyBoard extends Robot{
public KeyBoard throws java.awt.AWTException{
//constructor body.
}
//other methods.
}
```

For more information, you can read the documentation of the Robot class [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html).